# Scrape text from a node with multiple descendants with Scrapy

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape rows like the one below from an HTML table with Scrapy:

```
<tr bgcolor="#F3F1E6">

  <td class="htable_eng_text" align="center">
    <a href="results.asp?racedate=02/02/2014&amp;raceno=08&amp;venue=ST" class="htable_eng_text">
      368
    </a>
  </td>

  <td class="htable_eng_text" align="center">
    02/02/14
  </td>

  <td class="htable_eng_text" align="center" nowrap="">
    ST / 
    <font title="TURF">
      "Turf" / 
    </font>
    "C         "
  </td>

  <td class="htable_eng_text" align="center">
    <font class="htable_eng_rpnarrow_text">
      4
    </font>
    <font class="htable_eng_rpnarrow_text">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;4
    </font>
    <font class="htable_eng_rpnarrow_text">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;3
    </font>
    <font class="htable_eng_rpnarrow_text">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;2
    </font>
    <font class="htable_eng_rpnarrow_text">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;5
    </font>
</tr>
```

I want the output to be:

```
['368',
'02/02/14',
'ST / "Turf" / "C     "',
'4 4 3 2 5']
```

My current Xpath attempt is as follows:

```
sel.xpath('td//text()[normalize-space()]').extract()
```

It works fine if the text is just inside the `<td>` tags or if the nested tags don't branch (e.g. first and second cell).  But this causes problems if the cell contains multiple descendants (e.g. third and fourth cell) because I my Xpath returns a separate element for each of the descendants, but I want them to be concatenated together.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> h = '''
... <table>
... <tr bgcolor="#F3F1E6">
... ...
... </tr>
... </table>
... '''
>>>
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> import re
>>> def normalize(xs):
...     text = ''.join(xs)
...     text = text.strip()
...     return re.sub(r'[\s\xa0]+', ' ', text)
...
>>> root = Selector(text=h, type='html')
>>> print [normalize(x.xpath('.//text()').extract()) for x in root.xpath('.//td')]
[u'368', u'02/02/14', u'ST / "Turf" / "C "', u'4 4 3 2 5']
```